# How do I stop horizontal dragging on my website

Tags: css, reactjs, iphone, web, mobile-website

as Im making my new React Web App, I noticed when open on an Iphone, if the user drags horizontally it renders some blank space and makes the website functionality awfull, for androids though, this doesnt happen, do you guys have any hints?
My website URL-
https://werepairsuporte.com.pt/
PS- I dont have a SSL certificate yet as my website is not fully ready, hope you can understand that.

Comment: overflowX: hidden

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that one of your elements is wider than the viewport of the iphone, using the console delete elements one by one til you find the offending one then use breakpoints to amend the width.

either to just add this to your css.

```
body {
   overflow-x: none
}
```